# Symfony2 serve open pdf file

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I need to serve pdf files through the controller, but I can't make them open in browser window. When I send response with pdf file, it renders gibberish, or if I follow example at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files it downloads the file, but I need to open it in view mode, how can I do that?

Here's what I'v got so far:

```
return new Response(readfile('/file/path/file.pdf'), 200,
    array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf')
);
```

Am I missing something, or maybe there's something wrong with my php or apache configuration?

Comment: try to set `Content-Disposition: inline; filename.pdf` Header.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Found a solution:

Add BinaryFileResponse before controller class declaration from [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files)

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
```

In controller action return BinaryFileResponse

```
return new BinaryFileResponse('/file/path/file.pdf');
```

Answer (score -5):

I have the same issue

Try to add this :

```
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
.......
return  $response->headers->set('Content-type' , 'application/pdf');
```